# number input events in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The listelements are hidden by default, I'd like to select a number from the 'postnr' number input then show the listelements. I'm not sure what event I should be using with DOM. I figured I have to somehow loop through the list then run it same number of times as the input. Any advice?

```js
let blogNr = document.getElementById("postnr");
var scene  = document.getElementById("blogposts");

blogNr.oncontextmenu {
  console.log("you changed the form");
}
```

```css
ul {
  font-size : 20px;
  padding   : 10%;
  display   : none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="postnr" name="postnr" min="0" max="5">

<ul id="blogposts">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae fugit ut quod reiciendis asperiores animi vitae incidunt aspernatur ullam autem.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae fugit ut quod reiciendis asperiores animi vitae incidunt aspernatur ullam autem.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae fugit ut quod reiciendis asperiores animi vitae incidunt aspernatur ullam autem.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wrong  JS code updte to `blogNr.oncontextmenu = e => {`

Comment: there is no form element in your snippet why ?

Comment: why are you using `contextmenu` event ? this just a right click event !

Comment: did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? You should !

Comment: What's wrong with `contextmenu`? It's impossible to listen to right click without it

Comment: may be start with this one first ! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use the contextmenu/right click, as long as you respect JS syntax, but that has nothing to do with some changes into an imaginary form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your reference, here is a list of events - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Not sure what you are asking exactly, so here are some possible solutions:

1. You want the `<ul>` element to show when `<input>` has a valid value:

```js
let blogNr = document.getElementById("postnr");
let scene  = document.getElementById("blogposts");

blogNr.addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
  const inputHasValue = !isNaN(event.target.value) && !!event.target.value;
  const useDisplayStyle = inputHasValue ? `block` : `none`;
  scene.style.display = useDisplayStyle;
});
```

2. You want the `<li>` element whose index matches the number input's value (for ex. if number is 1, show the first `<li>`) to show:

in that case, it would not make much sense or there is little benefit in using `<ul>` this way.

Comment: w3schools is a bad source

Comment: w3schools is a fine source; issues with it are historical. that link has correct info, at any rate.

Comment: Well for example I have a list with 3 list elements, if i set the input to 1 only the first element of the list is displayed while the rest are still hidden. Thanks anyway I think I can do this with a loop